# Trouble Computing Pi with Java

Tags: java, pi

I have been trying for a few days to compute pi using the series expansion `pi =  4(1-1/3+1/5-1/7...` but whenever I use the code I have below, it returns 4.0.

```
public class Pi {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        double pie = 0.0;
        int max = 1000;
        for (int x = 1 ; x < max ; x = x + 2) {
            if (x % 4 == 1) {
                pie+= 1/x;
            } else if (x % 4 == 3) {
                pie-=1/x;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(4*pie);
    }
}
```

In this, I am computing `pie` to a denominator below 1000. `Pie` is the variable that stores my value created for `pie`. At the end, it prints pi, but always returns 4.0.

Using the Debug feature in my IDE (`Eclipse`), I see the value of `pie` jumps to 4 from the initial value of 0, but then does not change for the rest of the times the program increments the value of `x` in the for loop, it does not do anything to pi.

Comment: 4.0 for Pi is not so bad ;-) SCNR

Comment: You're doing integer division. You need to use floating division. This is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

You are performing integer division with `1/x`, which always results in an `int`, truncating the true decimal value.  `1/1` is `1`, but `1` divided by anything larger is `0` in Java, so your result will always be `4`.

Use a `double` literal to force floating-point division.

```
pie += 1.0 / x;  // and pie -= 1.0 / x;
```

Alternatively, you can cast `1` to a `double`.

```
pie += (double) 1 / x;  // and pie -= (double) 1 / x;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last one just be `pie += (double) 1 / x;`?

Comment: @VivinPaliath Yes.  I copied/pasted, but I meant `(double) 1 / x` to demonstrate casting as an alternative.  Updated.

Comment: @rgettman Oh, no worries. I figured it might be a typo - I have done similar things myself many times :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are performing integer division and adding the result to a double. `x` is an `int` and `1` is an `int`. When you divide an integer by an integer, you get back an integer. Hence what you're adding to `pie` is always an integer.

The first time you run the loop, you evaluate the expression `1/1`, which returns just `1` (an integer) and assigns that value to `pie`. For everything else after, you get `0`, which means that `pie` doesn't change. Hence when you finally print `4 * pie`, you get `4`.

There are a few options:

- Use `double` everywhere.
- Change `pie += 1 / x;` to `pie += (1.0 / x);` (and the same for the other one)
- Cast `1` to `double` before adding to `pie`: `pie += (double) 1 / x`.

Comment: With all the `code` emphasis, this is a bit `annoying` to read.

Comment: I find it enhances readability. I like to call out variables and keywords by using `code`.

Comment: Yeah, but doing it everywhere means you call attention to everything, thus setting nothing apart. rgettman's  answer is much easier to read, since the actual code is formatted on its own line. Though, I only voted for his over yours since it was posted first.

Comment: I'm not sure using it on `x`, `int`, and expressions like `1/1` translates to using it "everywhere". Perhaps I could have reworded my answer so that usages aren't so close together. Also the usage of `code` in rgettman's answer isn't just limited to the actual code examples - he uses it in regular text too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are making an integer division which returns less than zero. As an integer, the value will be rounded to zero instead. This adds zero to pie on each iteration.

What you need to do is to replace the literal integer ones, to literal floating point ones, like this

```
package cl.misc.pi;

public class Pi {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double pie = 0.0;
        int max = 1000;
        for (int x = 1; x < max; x = x + 2) {
            if (x % 4 == 1) {
                pie += 1.00 / x;
            } else if (x % 4 == 3) {
                pie -= 1.00 / x;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(4 * pie);
    }
}
```

As you see, I did replace `pie += 1 / x` for `pie += 1.00 / x` which now adds a floating point result to pie.

Result of this routine is `3.139592655589785`